# Вывод в таблицу ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

вывожу в один `<td id="steam-id"></td>`

```
success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#steam-id").text(data.steamid);
        }
```

Но это одну ячейку таблицы, а если их у меня много, не писать же на каждое поле ид и через него присваивать значение.

Например столько, как вывести пришедшие данные в таблицу?

```
{
    "steamid": "76561198049827777",
    "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
    "profilestate": 1,
    "personaname": "tlmcmerty",
```

Comment: Заменить `id` на `class` и воспользоваться `.eq()`

Comment: Выводит в ячейки [object Object]

Comment: Ну покажите пример кода, что тут судить-то.

Comment: Код лучше добавлять в вопрос, а не в комментарии. Вам там предложили уже ответ неленивые люди :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну например так:

```js
var data = {
    "steamid": "76561198049827777",
    "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
    "profilestate": 1,
    "personaname": "tlmcmerty"};
    
var table = $('table');

var str = '<tr>';
for (var prop in data) {
  str += '<td>' + data[prop] + '</td>';  
}

str += '</tr>';

table.append(str);
```

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```